# working with deferred results in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, restangular

Can't seem to get my head over the concept of 'promise' in AngularJS, I am using the restangular library to fetch a resource over REST, however I always get null results. Here's the code

```
.service('CareersService', [ 'Restangular', '$sce', function(Restangular, $sce){
            var vacancies = [];
            var result;
          this.getVacancies = function() {
                Restangular.all('job_posts').getList({active: 'true'}).then(function(job_posts){
                job_posts.forEach(function(job_post){
                    vacancies.push(_.pick(job_post,['id','title','min_experience','max_experience','location']));
                })  
            })
            return vacancies;
          }
            this.getVacancy = function(job_id){
                    Restangular.one('job_posts',job_id).get().then(function(job_post){
                    result = _.pick(job_post, 'title','min_experience','max_experience','location','employment_type','description');
                    var safe_description = $sce.trustAsHtml(result.description);
                        var emp_type = _.capitalize(result.employment_type);
                        _.set(result, 'description', safe_description);
                        _.set(result, 'employment_type', emp_type);
            });
              return result;            
            }
    }]).controller('DetailsCtrl', ['$scope' ,'$stateParams', 'CareersService' ,function($scope, $stateParams, CareersService) {

          $scope.data.vacancy = { title: 'Loading ...', contents: ''    };

          $scope.data.vacancy = CareersService.getVacancy($stateParams.job_id);

}])
```

and then in view

```
<div class="container">
    <a ui-sref="careers" class="btn btn-primary">Show All</a>
    <div class="row">
        <h2>{{ data.vacancy.title }}</h2>
        <p>{{ data.vacancy.min_experience }}</p>
        <p>{{ data.vacancy.max_experience }}</p>
        <p>{{ data.vacancy.location }}</p>
        <p>{{ data.vacancy.employment_type }}</p>
        <p ng-bind-html="data.vacancy.description"></p>     
    </div>
</div>
```

Am I missing something in the way to use promises?

---

***Update***

here's the updated code thanks to all the help I got here,

```
          this.getVacancies = function() {
                Restangular.all('job_posts').getList({active: 'true'}).then(function(job_posts){
                job_posts.forEach(function(job_post){
                    vacancies.push(_.pick(job_post,['id','title','min_experience','max_experience','location']));
                })
                return vacancies;   
            })
          }
         this.getVacancy = function(job_id){
                    Restangular.one('job_posts',job_id).get().then(function(job_post){
                    vacancy = _.pick(job_post, 'title','min_experience','max_experience','location','employment_type','description');
                    ...
                    return vacancy;
            });
            }
}])
```

And in controllers

```
  CareersService.getVacancy($stateParams.job_id).then(function (vacancy){
            $scope.data.vacancy = vacancy;
          });
```

and

```
  CareersService.getVacancies().then(function (vacancies){
        $scope.data.vacancies = vacancies;
  });
```

I now get the error

`Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

At the line

```
CareersService.getVacancies().then(function(vacancies) {
```

Comment: have you logged out what vacancy contain? and also have you debuged and checked that you are getting data in service?

Comment: There is a call made to the service and that gives a success (well 304 now) response, so the data definitely is populated in job_post. Not sure why result does not get populated. undefined it says when I log to console before returning. Quite a noob with JS and Angular, so can't even figure out a good failing test for this, else would have shared that test too

Comment: `return vacancies/result` is executed **before** the `.then()` calls: [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: yes that's the issue move return statement inside then() after your loop.

Comment: Nada champs! moving it to inside the then block didn't help either ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restangular makes an API call over a http, and once it make a call it returns underlying promise object. And inside `.then` function of it you can get the data responded by API.

So here you are making an async call and considering it to happen it in synchronous way like you can see you had returned `result`/`vacancies` array from `Restangular` call, in that way `result`/`vacancies` is always going to be empty.

In such you should return a promise from a service method. And return appropriate formatted data from promise so that you can `chain` that promise in controller as well(by retrieving a data).

**Service**

```
this.getVacancies = function() {
  //returned Restangular promise
  return Restangular.all('job_posts').getList({
    active: 'true'
  }).then(function(job_posts) {
    job_posts.forEach(function(job_post) {
      vacancies.push(_.pick(job_post, ['id', 'title', 'min_experience', 'max_experience', 'location']));
    });
    //return calculated result
    return vacancies;
  })
}
this.getVacancy = function(job_id) {
  //returned Restangular promise
  return Restangular.one('job_posts', job_id).get().then(function(job_post) {
    result = _.pick(job_post, 'title', 'min_experience', 'max_experience', 'location', 'employment_type', 'description');
    var safe_description = $sce.trustAsHtml(result.description);
    var emp_type = _.capitalize(result.employment_type);
    _.set(result, 'description', safe_description);
    _.set(result, 'employment_type', emp_type);
    //returned result to chain promise
    return result;
  });
}
```

As I said now you can easily chain promise inside controller by having `.then` function over service method call.

```
CareersService.getVacancy($stateParams.job_id).then(function(result){
    $scope.data.vacancy = result;
});
```

---

**Update**

The syntax without `.then` would work, but you need to make small change in it by adding `.$object` after a method call.

```
$scope.data.vacancy = CareersService.getVacancy($stateParams.job_id).$object;
```

`$object` is property which added inside promise object by `Restangular`. While making an API call, at that time it makes `$scope.data.vacancy` value as a blank array (`[]`) and once server respond with response, it fills that object with response received by server. Behind the scene it only updates the value of `$object` property which automatically update `$scope.data.vacancy` value.

Same behaviour is there in `$resource` of `ngResource`.

---

I wanted to also put down that when you're chaining promise, that time you have to explicitly handle error case. Whereas in current code you haven't handle such failure condition. So I'd suggest you to go for that as well by adding `error` function inside `Restangular` REST API call. and do use `$q.reject('My error data, this can be object as well')`.

Comment: Okay so basically `$scope.data.vacancy = CareersService.getVacancy($stateParams.job_id);` or `$scope.data.vacancies = CareersService.getVacancies();` both exectue without waiting for the results to be populated? I thought because I',m processing the results under then block in service that would not be the case.

Comment: On a curious note, `$scope.data.vacancies = CareersService.getVacancies();` does end up rendering the index view with a list vacancies fetched in first batch, so still a bit confused.

Comment: @AnadiMisra here you go, I added explanation for that as well.

Comment: Now that change gives me '`angular.self.js?body=1:13921 TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at new <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/assets/site/jobs.self.js?body=1:68:60)` which is exactly the line where I'm calling then ....

Comment: Have You returned promise of Restangular? Like I shown in answer

Comment: yes I have, added update to the question. I'm a bit more confused now between promise, deferred and callbacks :-)

Comment: What confusion you're having? I explained everything, what else you want?

Comment: Lol! Naah it's my noon-ness on play here, finally managed writing a test using Jasmine and I realised I was not returning the Promise object :-), thanks for you help

Comment: Np, that happens when developer develop a code. Please to hear that my answer helped, Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are making a async call to get the result. So you need either a callback or [promise](http://www.mattgreer.org/articles/promises-in-wicked-detail/) to handle this. One option with minimum code change is to make the service to return promise and in the controller get the result via `then`

```
.service('CareersService', ['Restangular', '$sce', function(Restangular, $sce) {
  var vacancies = [];
  var result;
  this.getVacancies = function() {
    Restangular.all('job_posts').getList({
      active: 'true'
    }).then(function(job_posts) {
      job_posts.forEach(function(job_post) {
        vacancies.push(_.pick(job_post, ['id', 'title', 'min_experience', 'max_experience', 'location']));
      })
    })
    return vacancies;
  }
  this.getVacancy = function(job_id) {
    return Restangular.one('job_posts', job_id).get().then(function(job_post) {
      result = _.pick(job_post, 'title', 'min_experience', 'max_experience', 'location', 'employment_type', 'description');
      var safe_description = $sce.trustAsHtml(result.description);
      var emp_type = _.capitalize(result.employment_type);
      _.set(result, 'description', safe_description);
      _.set(result, 'employment_type', emp_type);
      return result;
    });
  }
}]).controller('DetailsCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'CareersService', function($scope, $stateParams, CareersService) {

  $scope.data.vacancy = {
    title: 'Loading ...',
    contents: ''
  };

  CareersService.getVacancy($stateParams.job_id).then(function(result) {
    $scope.data.vacancy = result;
  });

}])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing return outside of then try to move it inside in then function

```
this.getVacancies = function() {

            Restangular.all('job_posts').getList({active: 'true'}).then(function(job_posts){
            job_posts.forEach(function(job_post){
                vacancies.push(_.pick(job_post,['id','title','min_experience','max_experience','location']));
            })  
            return vacancies;
        })           
      }
```